# database config in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

[my xampp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JPAF.png)when I installed xampp on windows i changed the localhost to localhost:122 , it's working now , but when i run laravel , i can't access to mysql from it . this is my database.php config and what changes are required?

```
mysql => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'port' => '3306',
    'database' => 'web_shop',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'unix_socket' => '',
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    ]
```

Comment: If you changed the port, you need to change the port above from 3306 to your port.

Comment: start your xampp, start apache and mysql, make a screenshot and post it here

Comment: Normally you can make all the changes you need in your ```.env``` file ind your project root. There you have options for port, database etc.

Comment: I posted may xmapp img , please answer more accurate , thanks

Answer (score 0):

Laravel makes it very easy to manage your database connections through **app/config/database.php**

As you noted, it is looking for a database called 'database'. The reason being that this is the default name in the database configuration file.

```
'mysql' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'database', <------ Default name for database
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => '',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
```

Change this to the name of the database that you would like to connect to like this:

```
'mysql' => array(
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'database'  => 'my_awesome_data', <------ change name for database
    'username'  => 'root',            <------ remember credentials
    'password'  => '',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
),
```

you will easily be able to access your database!

Comment: thank u , I did it correctly , I think the trouble is about changing the localhost port and can't set with mysql